# Is it possible to get photos from device without screen?

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen

I have Sony Xpreria Z3 with broken screen which. I need to retrieve all photos from that device but when I try to connect it to the pc I get message that first I need to unlock the screen but I cant do it as the screen is broken...

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), where similar issues are listed.

Answer (score 0):

If your screen still works, but can't be controled, use a computer mouse to unlock your phone

Answer (score 0):

You can control your phone from the computer using [vysor](http://vysor.io) even on broken screens. Try it!